# Refactor large models.py file in Django app

Tags: django, django-models

After reading monokrome's answer to [Where should Django manager code live?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883322/where-should-django-manager-code-live), I've decided to split a large `models.py` into smaller, more manageable files. I'm using the folder structure

```
foodapp/
    models/
        __init__.py #contains pizza model
        morefood.py #contains hamburger & hotdog models
```

In `__init__.py`, I import the models from `morefood.py` with

```
from morefood import hamburger, hotdog
```

However, when I run `python manage.py syncdb`, the only table created is `foodapp_pizza` - What do I need to do to get Django to create tables for the models I have imported from `morefood.py`?

Comment: Everyone has different ideas of how large a file is "too large," but in general I find that if an app requires refactoring of its models.py, that generally indicates an app that isn't doing "just one thing" and it's the app itself that needs to be refactored into multiple apps. Just a thought.

Comment: Both answers below work well. I prefer kibitzer's slightly belows it I can keep all the models in the models folder. I'll keep an eye on the ticket (http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6961) mentioned in the blog post that Baresi mentions.

Comment: @Carl – good point. In this particular case, I have ended up splitting the app into two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or, in your morefood.py models, add the following to the Meta:

```
class Meta:
    app_label = 'foodapp'
```

Then syncdb will work with your existing structure

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
foodapp/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    /morefood
        __init__.py
        hamburger.py
        hotdog.py
```

and do this in models.py:

```
from foodapp.morefood.hamburger import *
from foodapp.morefood.hotdog import *
```

as suggested in [this blogpost](https://justin.abrah.ms/this-and-that/fitures_model_subdir.html).

Comment: Blog posting is now 404, but this article seems to be the same content: http://www.justinlilly.com/this-and-that/fitures_model_subdir.html